# Brightcove HTML5 Player full screen event

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, brightcove, video-player

In Brightcove documentation, [they mention ENTER_FULLSCREEN and EXIT_FULLSCREEN events.](https://docs.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/player/com/brightcove/api/modules/ExperienceModule.html#event:enterFullScreen)

I couldn't find those events in the 'brightcove.api.events.ExperienceEvent' object.
I had to use browsers full screen events instead:

```
       jQuery(document).on('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange MSFullscreenChange',fullScreenChangeHandler);
```

I feel it's a hack, because Brightcove documentation states they do support player fullscreen events. Besides, on browser fullscreen event, I don't know if the video player entered or exited the full screen mode.

Is there any videoplayer full screen events for Brightcove HTML5 player ?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML5 smart player doesn't have full screen events. The doc links you have are for an older player API version for the Flash player only.

If you add a js plugin to a smart player, it will run inside the HTML5 player  iframe and be able to listen to the video element's full screen events.

Comment: And how do I do it? I couldn't find any player full screen events